# Not able to calculate average with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, mongotemplate

I wonder that I can't get calculate the average with Spring 5 and MongoDB.

In the database are 40 entries with this format

> Result(id=5e4adeca9eab5f052e2ac239, date=2020-02-12,
>   value=1.048097596376957)

I'm interested to get the date from t1 to t2 and the average of all matches.

The code which I wrote and ens in an NPE looks like this:

```
    MatchOperation filterDate = match(Criteria.where("date").gte(startWeek).lte(now));
    GroupOperation groupByValue = group("value").avg("value").as("averageValue");

    Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(filterDate, groupByValue);
    AggregationResults<Document> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "unknown", Document.class);

    Document document = result.getUniqueMappedResult();
    document.getDouble("averageValue");
```

When getDouble will be invoked a NPE happens.
The matchCriteria is in my opinion correct.
By the GroupOperation I have my doubts.

> 2020-02-17 19:43:22.661 DEBUG 10148 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
>   o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate      : Executing aggregation: [{
>   "$match" : { "date" : { "$gte" : { "$date" : 1581289200000}, "$lte" :
>   { "$date" : 1581894000000}}}}, { "$group" : { "_id" : "$value",
>   "averageValues" : { "$avg" : "$value"}}}] in collection unkown

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;


public class Result {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private LocalDate date;

    private Double value;

    public Result(LocalDate date, Double value) {
        this.date = date;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

I wonder about the grouping. It this necessary?
And do I need a collection?

Answer (score 1):

To calculate `avg`, you need to `$group` similar records and use `$avg` operator.

In your case, you want calculate **average of all matches**, but I guess you don't have a field with the same value for all filtered matches. In this case, you may order MongoDB group by `null` to calculate average.

Change your `Group` stage to below:

```
GroupOperation groupByValue = group().avg("value").as("averageValue");
```

which will be translated to:

```
{ "$group" : { "_id" : null, "averageValues" : { "$avg" : "$value"}}
```